# map-factory node.js append data to existing array

Tags: node.js, objectmapper

Using map-factory https://github.com/midknight41/map-factory when adding additional items to an array, it only adds the last item.

Tried:

```
const customers = [
    {
      controlNumber: "043019",
      uuid: "4d2ea517-81ca-4c9e-af5a-2ea277278fc5-M2AM7GW0",
    },
  ]
const mapper = createMapper();
mapper 
    .map("uuid").to("customerParty[].idList[].id")
    .map("uId").to("customerParty[].idList[].typeId", typeId => typeId, () => "uId")
    .set("customerParty[].idList[].id", controlNumber => controlNumber)
    .set("customerParty[].idList[].typeId", typeId => typeId, () => "Other")
mapper.execute(customer)
```

Expected:

```
customerParty {
    idList[{
        id:4d2ea517-81ca-4c9e-af5a-2ea277278fc5-M2AM7GW0,
        typeId:'uId'
    },
    {
        id:043019,
        typeId:'Other'
    }
    ]
}
```

Returned:

```
customerParty {
    idList[
    {
        id:043019,
        typeId:'Other'
    }
    ]
}
```